# Pandas Dataframe and excel datetime challenges with messy accounting data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, accounting

I frequently work with messy accounting data, which is often in excel files. When I load an excel file into a dataframe using the following, I get 00:00:00 added to the end. I want to preserve the original date format the accountant has created so that I can extract it, but I cannot extract a date as a string when the date is formatted like this. Could someone explain this fixed behaviour and how to prevent it?

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('GLQ1.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'JNS512051', header=None, skiprows=8)
df.head()

0   01002-0 Bank-Current    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     Opening Balance Sep 30/18   NaN     NaN     666034
2   2018-10-01 00:00:00     CR  CR8729  CR8729  Fast Cash Receipts  3868.61     -   NaN
3   2018-10-01 00:00:00     CR  CR8732  CR8732  Fast Cash Receipts  13348.4     -   NaN
4   2018-10-02 00:00:00     CR  CR8733  CR8733  Fast Cash Receipts  9671.88     -   NaN
```

Comment: This looks like it is actually in a normal datetime format with year / month / day / hour / minute / second but that in the excel it just had year / month / day.  Do you want this back into just the year / month / day format?

Answer (score 0):

when importing xlsx files you can easily prevent pandas from interpreting possible data types and leave them as it is. You can achieve this using `dtypes` parameter in `pd.read_excel()` function like so:

```
df = pd.read_excel(xls, 'JNS512051', header=None, skiprows=8, dtypes=object)
```